# Upsampling Dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe indexed by month, I'd like to reindex by day (upsample). Values that were previously indexed by month should now be divided by the number of days in the month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
tidx_m = pd.date_range('2011-01-31', periods=2, freq='M')
tidx_d = pd.date_range('2011-01-01', '2011-02-28', freq='D')

d = pd.Series(100, tidx_m)
d.reindex(tidx_d, fill_value=0).groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M')).transform('mean')
```

yields

```
2011-01-01    3.225806
2011-01-02    3.225806
2011-01-03    3.225806
2011-01-04    3.225806
2011-01-05    3.225806
2011-01-06    3.225806
2011-01-07    3.225806
2011-01-08    3.225806
2011-01-09    3.225806
2011-01-10    3.225806
2011-01-11    3.225806
2011-01-12    3.225806
2011-01-13    3.225806
2011-01-14    3.225806
2011-01-15    3.225806
2011-01-16    3.225806
2011-01-17    3.225806
2011-01-18    3.225806
2011-01-19    3.225806
2011-01-20    3.225806
2011-01-21    3.225806
2011-01-22    3.225806
2011-01-23    3.225806
2011-01-24    3.225806
2011-01-25    3.225806
2011-01-26    3.225806
2011-01-27    3.225806
2011-01-28    3.225806
2011-01-29    3.225806
2011-01-30    3.225806
2011-01-31    3.225806
2011-02-01    3.571429
2011-02-02    3.571429
2011-02-03    3.571429
2011-02-04    3.571429
2011-02-05    3.571429
2011-02-06    3.571429
2011-02-07    3.571429
2011-02-08    3.571429
2011-02-09    3.571429
2011-02-10    3.571429
2011-02-11    3.571429
2011-02-12    3.571429
2011-02-13    3.571429
2011-02-14    3.571429
2011-02-15    3.571429
2011-02-16    3.571429
2011-02-17    3.571429
2011-02-18    3.571429
2011-02-19    3.571429
2011-02-20    3.571429
2011-02-21    3.571429
2011-02-22    3.571429
2011-02-23    3.571429
2011-02-24    3.571429
2011-02-25    3.571429
2011-02-26    3.571429
2011-02-27    3.571429
2011-02-28    3.571429
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Could the same be done if additionally, a column were needed in the groupby? In other words, the dates are only unique by the index plus this additional column.

Comment: Asked a new question for previous comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917259/upsampling-dataframe-in-pandas-with-index-column

Comment: @BrianBien yes, and a new question was appropriate