# Upsampling Dataframe in Pandas with Index + Column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe indexed by month, I'd like to reindex by day (upsample). Values that were previously indexed by month should now be divided by the number of days in the month. In addition to the index, a column should be used in the grouping. Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878170/upsampling-dataframe-in-pandas#) - just with a column also being used in the grouping.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1234)
tidx_m = pd.date_range('2011-01-31', periods=5, freq='M')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, (5, 2)), columns=['class', 'val'])
df.index = tidx_m
df = pd.concat([df, df])
df.ix[:5, 'class'] = 0
df.ix[5:, 'class'] = 1
print(df)

            class  val
2011-01-31      0    1
2011-02-28      0    1
2011-03-31      0    0
2011-04-30      0    1
2011-05-31      0    1
2011-01-31      1    1
2011-02-28      1    1
2011-03-31      1    0
2011-04-30      1    1
2011-05-31      1    1
```

After upsampling the index to days instead of months, I'd like to group by the Datetime index *and* `class`. Values in "val" should be redistributed throughout all days in the month (e.g. 1 becomes 1 / 31 for each day in January).

Comment: Can you add sample data and desired output?

Comment: In real data are duplicates in index? Is possible omit `df = pd.concat([df, df])` ?

Comment: And thank you for sample.

Comment: I fixed the example so that data is not duplicate when grouped by both the index and class column.

Answer (score 1):

First is necessary add new row to `DataFrame` with values of first row and index value with same index, only with first day of month.

Then divide column `val` by [`DatetimeIndex.day`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.day.html) and last use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html) and [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tseries.resample.Resampler.ffill.html) new values.

```
df.val = df.val.div(df.index.day)

first_idx = df.index[0] - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
print (first_idx)
2011-01-01 00:00:00

first_class_val = df.iloc[0]
print (first_class_val)
class    0.000000
val      0.032258
Name: 2011-01-31 00:00:00, dtype: float64

df.loc[ first_idx] = first_class_val
print (df)
            class       val
2011-01-31    0.0  0.032258
2011-02-28    0.0  0.035714
2011-03-31    0.0  0.000000
2011-04-30    0.0  0.033333
2011-05-31    0.0  0.032258
2011-01-31    1.0  0.032258
2011-02-28    1.0  0.035714
2011-03-31    1.0  0.000000
2011-04-30    1.0  0.033333
2011-05-31    1.0  0.032258
2011-01-01    0.0  0.032258
```

```
df1 = df.groupby('class').resample('D').ffill().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

print (df1)
            class       val
2011-01-01    0.0  0.032258
2011-01-02    0.0  0.032258
2011-01-03    0.0  0.032258
2011-01-04    0.0  0.032258
2011-01-05    0.0  0.032258
2011-01-06    0.0  0.032258
2011-01-07    0.0  0.032258
2011-01-08    0.0  0.032258
2011-01-09    0.0  0.032258
2011-01-10    0.0  0.032258
2011-01-11    0.0  0.032258
2011-01-12    0.0  0.032258
2011-01-13    0.0  0.032258
2011-01-14    0.0  0.032258
2011-01-15    0.0  0.032258
...
...
```

Comment: This appears to provide multiple days only for months following January. I am expecting 31 days for January. Since the first `val` is `1` in Jan, each val after the operation should equal 1 / 31.

Comment: Also, the same class for a day in any given month should have the same value, since the month's `val` gets divided among the days in that month / class combo.

Comment: It looks like we still have multiple values for the same month + class combination

Comment: So you need same values?

Comment: The idea is that in "upsampling," the value that previously applied to one month now is distributed evenly across all days in that month. So a value of `1` for a month would be distributed to all 31 days of Jan as `1/31` (as a float), for example

Comment: Yes, I was no sure if is neccessary first or last divide values. It seems first. Please check it.